# Eigenvector of a two-level system with Hamiltonian $H=h\cdot\sigma$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I mostly want a clarification of the first step to solve this problem. The question reads

> Consider a two-level system with a Hamiltonian of the form $$H = \vec h\cdot\vec\sigma$$ where $\vec\sigma$ has
> the Pauli matrices as its components. Calculate the eigenvalues of $H$ and interpret
> the corresponding eigenvectors.
> (Hint: You do not need to give the explicit form of the eigenvectors).

Say $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary eigenvalue of $\vec\sigma$ then we have
$$\vec h\cdot\vec\sigma\psi=\epsilon\psi.$$

The step that confuses me is how this becomes
$$[\vec h\vec\sigma+\epsilon\sigma_0][\vec h\vec\sigma-\epsilon\sigma_0]\psi=0.$$
Onwards from here is pretty straight forward, I just need to use the anti-commutating relation.

Comment: If this is a two-level system and $\sigma$'s are the Pauli matrix can you specify what do you mean by $\sigma_0$ in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\vec h\cdot\vec\sigma\psi=\epsilon\sigma_0\psi,$$
as $\sigma_0$ is the indentity. Subtract the RHS from both sides and collect terms to write
$$[\vec h\cdot\vec{\sigma}-\epsilon\sigma_0]\psi=0.$$

Note that the Pauli matrices (aside from $\sigma_0$) are all traceless. Any linear combination of traceless matrices is traceless, so $\vec h\cdot \vec\sigma$ is traceless. The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, so if one eigenvalue is $\epsilon$, the other must be $-\epsilon$. This tells us that
$$[\vec h\cdot\vec\sigma+\epsilon\sigma_0]\psi=0.$$
This can be multiplied with the first eigenvalue equation to yield
$$[\vec h\cdot\vec\sigma-\epsilon\sigma_0][\vec h\cdot\vec\sigma+\epsilon\sigma_0]\psi=0.$$
as desired.

Comment: Oh, well I overcomplicated way too much in my head, I kept thinking I needed to use some Pauli matrix identity and didn't see the straightforward path, thank you very much!

Comment: Please see my edited response. I realized the argument I provided was flawed and corrected it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Wait but why was your previous answer flawed? I can see why this one is more failsafe but the previous one is fully correct or?

Comment: There wasn’t exactly anything wrong with the derivation, but you couldn’t conclude from it that $-\epsilon$ is also an eigenvalue. It’s just the statement that if $x=0$ then $xy=0$, but this does not imply that $y=0$.